# Fitting a lot of text onto a slide using shrink

Tags: beamer

Despite this being against the convention of making good presetations, I would like to fit a lot of text onto a single slide. Using \frame[shrink]{}, the text is fitted onto a single slide, but it does not fill it out, instead forming a column. How can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[style=mla,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{subfig}
\graphicspath{ {charts/} }
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{caption}
\AtBeginSection[]
\usetheme{Berlin}



\begin{document}

\frametitle{Die Zweite Republik (1931-36)} 
\frame[shrink]{
In dem bestehenden Machtvakuum werden Kommunalwahlen abgehalten. Die Sozialisten und Republikaner erhalten die Mehrheit der Stimmen in den Städten, die Konservativen auf dem Land, sodass in mehreren spanischen Städten die Republik ausgerufen wird. Nationale Wahlen wurden daraufhin abgehalten, linke und links-republikanische Parteien erhalten die Mehrheit. Die Verfassung von 1931 war demokratisch, laizistisch und machte Dezentalisierung möglich. Auf der rechten Seite formiert sich die Confederación Española de Derechas Autónomas (CEDA), welche das gesamt rechte Spektrum abdeckte. Vor dem Hintergrund zunehmender politischer Radikalisierung gewinnt die CEDA 1932 die Wahlen. Als CEDA drei Minister in die Regierung einbringen wollte, kommt es zum erfolglosen anti-faschistischem Putsch von links, der vor allem in Asturien brutal niedergeschlagen wurde. Das linke Spektrum kommt daraufhin in einer Frente Popular zusammen, das politische Chaos nimmt weiter zu. Der erfolglose Coup der Rechten, angeführt vom Militär (Sanjurjo, Goded, Mola sowie Franco) und unterstützt von CEDA und rechten Organisationen (der faschistischen Falange und den Juntas de Ofensiva Nacional Sindicalista (JONS)) in 1936, führte zum Bürgerkrieg.
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple font command (e.g. `\scriptsize`). Please note that your code contains errors (like `\AtBeginSection[]` without mandatory argument).

[image: much text]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usetheme{Berlin}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Die Zweite Republik (1931-36)} 
\scriptsize In dem bestehenden Machtvakuum werden Kommunalwahlen abgehalten. Die Sozialisten und Republikaner erhalten die Mehrheit der Stimmen in den Städten, die Konservativen auf dem Land, sodass in mehreren spanischen Städten die Republik ausgerufen wird. Nationale Wahlen wurden daraufhin abgehalten, linke und links-republikanische Parteien erhalten die Mehrheit. Die Verfassung von 1931 war demokratisch, laizistisch und machte Dezentalisierung möglich. Auf der rechten Seite formiert sich die Confederación Española de Derechas Autónomas (CEDA), welche das gesamt rechte Spektrum abdeckte. Vor dem Hintergrund zunehmender politischer Radikalisierung gewinnt die CEDA 1932 die Wahlen. Als CEDA drei Minister in die Regierung einbringen wollte, kommt es zum erfolglosen anti-faschistischem Putsch von links, der vor allem in Asturien brutal niedergeschlagen wurde. Das linke Spektrum kommt daraufhin in einer Frente Popular zusammen, das politische Chaos nimmt weiter zu. Der erfolglose Coup der Rechten, angeführt vom Militär (Sanjurjo, Goded, Mola sowie Franco) und unterstützt von CEDA und rechten Organisationen (der faschistischen Falange und den Juntas de Ofensiva Nacional Sindicalista (JONS)) in 1936, führte zum Bürgerkrieg.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

To quote from the [beamer manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer):

> `shrink=⟨minimum shrink percentage⟩` [...] Since the shrinking takes place only after everything has been typeset, **shrunk frame text will not fill the frame completely horizontally**. For this reason, you can specify a `⟨minimum shrink percentage⟩` like 20. If this percentage is specified, the frame will be shrunk
>   at least
>   by this percentage. Since
>   beamer
>   knows this, **it can increase the horizontal width proportionally such that the shrunk text once more
>   fills the entire frame**. If, however, the percentage is not enough, the text will be shrunk as needed and
>   you will be punished with a warning message. [...]

Keeping this in mind, one could change your example to the follwing MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usetheme{Berlin}

\begin{document}
\frametitle{Die Zweite Republik (1931-36)} 
\frame[shrink=15]{
In dem bestehenden Machtvakuum werden Kommunalwahlen abgehalten. Die Sozialisten und Republikaner erhalten die Mehrheit der Stimmen in den Städten, die Konservativen auf dem Land, sodass in mehreren spanischen Städten die Republik ausgerufen wird. Nationale Wahlen wurden daraufhin abgehalten, linke und links-republikanische Parteien erhalten die Mehrheit. Die Verfassung von 1931 war demokratisch, laizistisch und machte Dezentalisierung möglich. Auf der rechten Seite formiert sich die Confederación Española de Derechas Autónomas (CEDA), welche das gesamt rechte Spektrum abdeckte. Vor dem Hintergrund zunehmender politischer Radikalisierung gewinnt die CEDA 1932 die Wahlen. Als CEDA drei Minister in die Regierung einbringen wollte, kommt es zum erfolglosen anti-faschistischem Putsch von links, der vor allem in Asturien brutal niedergeschlagen wurde. Das linke Spektrum kommt daraufhin in einer Frente Popular zusammen, das politische Chaos nimmt weiter zu. Der erfolglose Coup der Rechten, angeführt vom Militär (Sanjurjo, Goded, Mola sowie Franco) und unterstützt von CEDA und rechten Organisationen (der faschistischen Falange und den Juntas de Ofensiva Nacional Sindicalista (JONS)) in 1936, führte zum Bürgerkrieg.
}

\end{document}
```

[image]